# What does "Square-O" mean?

Tags: meaning, song-title, piano

There is a piece of piano music called [*Square-O* by Elissa Milne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT-YTIwWAZw). I would like to know the meaning of it.

Comment: Hi Emmal, welcome to our site.  Are you just looking for the meaning of the title?  The song seems too short and simple to allow for much meaningful musical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers to this question, whenever it is asked about any piece of art, be it music, sculpture, a novel, or whatever.

1) It means what it means to you.
2) It means what the author had in mind, and not all authors are willing to share that information.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you have also to consider that the artist may have had one thing in mind, but their audience over time may give the piece other associations.  anyhow, Elissa Milne has contact details [here](http://www.fabermusic.com/composers/elissa-milne/biography), and you could even get in touch to ask about the meaning of the piece

Comment: @Angst  what you said is what I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

There's a rondeau by Henry Purcell (ZT684), originally for the play Abdelazer, that was printed in some harpsichord collections with the title "Round-O". "Square-O" is probably a pun on that.

Comment: Another example:  "Blue Rondo a la Turk" -- Brubeck started with local folk rhythms, but I personally suspect (without any justification) that he sneaked a little of "Rondo alla Turca" in there as well :-)